# Is it possible to override #initialize in a Ruby module?

Tags: ruby

I have been trying to figure out how to extend the behavior of `initialize` from a module.  I want to do it without calling super in `initialize` of the class that is being mixed into.  I want to support the normal pattern of calling `include` I can't figure it out.  I've read everything I can find on the matter and, while people to have suggestions, none of them actually seem to work (in my hands at least).

Here is what I (think) I know:

- If it can be done at all, it has to be done using the hook on `include` (i.e. `Module.included(base)`).
- The `include` hook will execute before the including class defines `initialize` so there is no point to simply trying to define `initialize` with `base.instance_eval` because it will get overwritten.
- A suggestion was made to make use of the `method_added` hook and deal with it in there.  That is what I'm trying now but it appears that the hook executes at the beginning of method definition so you end up with what you see below.

  ```
  module Mo
    def self.included(klass)
      klass.instance_eval do
        def method_added(method)
          puts "Starting creation of #{method} for #{self.name}"
          case method
          when :initialize
            alias_method :original_initialize, :initialize
            puts "About to define initialize in Mo"
            def initialize
              original_initialize
              puts "Hello from Mo#initialize"
            end
            puts "Finished defining initialize in Mo"
          end
          puts "Finishing creation of #{method} for #{self.name}"
        end
      end
    end
  end

  class Foo
    include Mo
    def initialize
      puts "Hello from Foo#initialize"
    end
  end

  foo = Foo.new
  ```

This results in the following output:

```
    Starting creation of initialize for Foo
    Starting creation of original_initialize for Foo
    Finishing creation of original_initialize for Foo
    About to define initialize in Mo
    Finished defining initialize in Mo
    Finishing creation of initialize for Foo
    Hello from Foo#initialize
```

It looks to me like `initialize` from class Foo is still overwriting the definition from the module.  I'm guessing that this is because the definition is still open, suggesting that it isn't a matter of which block is started last be which is finished last that "wins".

If anyone out there really knows how to do this and have it work please enlighten me.

FWIW, yes, I think I have a good reason for wanting to do this.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you're on Ruby 2.0 or later, you can just use `prepend`. Either require the user to `prepend` rather than `include`, or do:

```
module Mo
  module Initializer
    def initialize
      puts "Hello from Mo#initialize"
      super
    end
  end

  def self.included(klass)
    klass.send :prepend, Initializer
  end
end
```

Comment: I discovered `prepend` shortly after asking the question.  I like it!  Still curious if there is a way to do it in 1.9.*

Comment: Is there anything obvious I am missing in using `klass.send :prepend` instead of simply `klass.prepend`?

Answer (score 7):

Ok, well in Ruby 1.9 you could add functionality to the `new` class method...

```
module Mo
  def new(*var)
    additional_initialize(*var)
    super(*var)
  end
  def additional_initialize(*var)
    puts "Hello from Mo"
  end
 end

class Foo
  extend Mo
  def initialize
    puts "Hello from Foo"
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
```

That returns...

```
Hello from Mo
Hello from Foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it satisfy to have a conditional call in Foo's initialize that only calls an included method if it's present?

```
module Mo
  def initialize_extra
    puts "Hello from Mo"
  end
end

class Foo
  include Mo
  def initialize
    if defined? initialize_extra
      initialize_extra
    else
      puts "Hello from Foo"
    end
  end
end

x = Foo.new
```

Comment: My goal is to not put any burden on the class other than the need to include the module.

Answer (score 0):

**If using Rails** you can also use `ActiveSupport::Concern` to do so like this:

```
module M
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    attr_reader :some_reader
  end

  def initialize
    puts 'module initialize'
  end
end

class Foo
  include M

  def initialize
    super
    puts 'class initialize'
  end
end
```

Calling `Foo.new` will output

```
module initialize
class initialize
```

You can also read [this](http://vaidehijoshi.github.io/blog/2015/10/13/stop-worrying-and-start-being-concerned-activesupport-concerns/) article if interested

Comment: Read the second sentence of my original post.  The whole point was to not do what you are suggesting.

Comment: @Huliax Ah, sorry, my bad. I was trying to solve my other problem, when saw your post, so it got mixed.